# Serial Port not working with arm64 in .Net Core 3.0 - Invalid Argument at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.set_DtrEnable(Boolean value)

Tags: c#, serial-port, arm64, .net-core-3.0, nvidia-jetson

We are getting below exception while opening Serial Port on arm64 Jetson board.
Its working fine on Linux computer but not on Jetson board.

Can someone please help on this to resolve?

> Invalid Argument
>
> at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.set_DtrEnable(Boolean value)      at
> System.IO.Ports.SerialStream..ctor

Code :

```
SerialPort _serialPort;
_serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB1", 4800, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
_serialPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;
_serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
_serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
 
try
  {
     var port = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
     Console.WriteLine("available ports : " + String.Join(",", port));
     Console.WriteLine("checking for open --- " + _serialPort.IsOpen);
     /// Check if connection is open or not, if not open it
     if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
       _serialPort.Open();
```

Comment: Is it working with the same USB to serial adaptor on your Linux computer? The error you see means the driver you have on your Jetson does not support `_serialPort.DtrEnable`. Are you using the DTR line? Have you checked if the driver loaded on the Jetson is the same as the one on your computer?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
No, both Jetson and Linux have their own different hardware and Jetson is at the remote location. 
Setting DTR is supported on the hardware - I checked documentation

Comment: It does not seem to be supported by the driver then, what driver are you using?

Comment: We are using Sierra Wireless GPS

Comment: That's the device you are connecting to, right? I meant the driver for your USB to serial adaptor, what is the output of `dmesg | grep /dev/ttyUSB1` on the Jetson?

Comment: We are using GobiSerial driver. `dmesg | grep /dev/ttyUSB1` gives me nothing but `cat /dev/ttyUSB1` gives me expected output which I need to grab using code. 
The workaround can be to grab the output of `cat /dev/ttyUSB1` by running shell command but that's not preferred

Comment: Now you got me confused, how are you activating flow control (DTR-RTS) to work with `cat`?

Comment: Now that I mentioned that, shouldn't you be writing `_serialPort.DtrEnable = True` capital T  instead of `true`

Comment: Hey, sorry for the confusion. I mean to get output on the command prompt and not through C# code. Capital T will give me a compilation error in C# code. I also tried removing the whole statement from the above code but then also it gives the same error

Comment: Removing `_serialPort.DtrEnable = true` gives a compilation error?

Comment: No, removing that line doesn't help as it still gives me the same error (`Invalid Argument  - at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.set_DtrEnable(Boolean value)`) so I don't think it is about Dtr but something else